# Use variables values from main.c in another file

Tags: c, variables, embedded, stm32, external

I'm trying to use variables values from my main.c in another file.c
`main.c`

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    uint32_t StatusReg = 0U;
    uint32_t NumberOfPeak = 0U;
    uint32_t Amplitude1 = 0U;
    uint32_t Amplitude2 = 0U, Amplitude3 = 0U, Amplitude4 = 0U, OldAmplitude1 = 0U;
    uint32_t  Distance1 = 0U;
    uint32_t Distance2 = 0U, OldDistance1 = 0U, Distance3 = 0U, Distance4 = 0U;
    uint8_t counter  = 0U;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, STATUS_CLEAR_REGW, 6, 5000);

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, NUMBER_PEAK_REGR, 2, 5000);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_NUMBER_PEAK, 4, 5000);

    NumberOfPeak = buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_NUMBER_PEAK[1U] << 8U);

    if (NumberOfPeak >= 0)
    {
            HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, DISTANCE1_REGR, 2, 5000);
            HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_DISTANCE, 4, 5000);

            HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, AMPLITUDE1_REGR, 2, 5000);
            HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, XM132_ADDR, buffer_AMPLITUDE, 4, 5000);

            Distance1 = buffer_DISTANCE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_DISTANCE[1U] << 8U);
            Amplitude1 = buffer_AMPLITUDE[0U] + ((uint32_t)buffer_AMPLITUDE[1U] << 8U);
        }
        if(OldDistance1 != Distance1)
            vPrint("Distance1 = %d mm \r\n", Distance1);
        if(OldAmplitude1 != Amplitude1)
            vPrint("Amplitude1 = %d \r\n", Amplitude1);
        OldDistance1 = Distance1;
        OldAmplitude1 = Amplitude1;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the Distance1 and Amplitude1 values from the main.c to use them in the ble_app.c

`ble_app.c`

```
extern void Temperature_Voltage_to_Distance(uint16_t distance, uint16_t amplitude);
static void GetDistance() {

  uint32_t amplitude =Amplitude1;
  uint32_t  distance =Distance1;
}
```

I'll use them after that in this file nad it worked when i ussed random values for amplitude and distance in ble_app.c

`tlm.c`

```
void Temperature_Voltage_to_Distance(uint16_t distance, uint16_t amplitude) {
  EddystoneTLM_InitStruct.BeaconTemperature = distance;
  EddystoneTLM_InitStruct.BatteryVoltage = amplitude;
}
```

Comment: You would have to pass them to `GetDistance` as parameters: `static void GetDistance(uint32_t distance,uint32_t amplitude)`, and from main call it with `GetDistance(Distance1,Amplitude1);`

Comment: You can move the `Distance1` and `Amplitude1` variables declarations outside their function (`main`) to make them global, then declare them as `extern uint32_t Distance1;` and `extern uint32_t Amplitude1;` where needed (preferably in a .h file that gets `#include`d by the .c file).

Comment: @IanAbbott ... which would be a [singularly bad idea](https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/)

Comment: Your `GetDistance()` does not do anything useful - it sets a pair of local variables that are discarded when the function returns..  You seem not to understand the concept of _local variables_, but _global variables_ are not an appropriate solution either.  You also appear not to understand the fundamental principles of _coupling_ and _cohesion_ in programming.  While it is easy to answer your question directly, it looks like an X-Y problem, and your solution Y that you are asking about is probably not the most appropriate solution to the real problem X that you are not telling us about.